# find an element under a <ul> <li> <a> "some text" </a> </li> </ul> tag as shown in figure

Tags: python, selenium, tags, element

This is the HTMl code, I want to get "1" and so on all values written in nested `<li> <a>` tags

[image: This is the HTMl code, I want to get "1" and so on all values written in nested <li> <a> tags]

I have tried

```
total = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='...']/following-sibling::a").text
```

and

```
totl = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ng-binding']")))
print (totl.text)
```

but nothing works. It will be a great favor if you let me out of it.

Comment: What do you mean by _nothing works_ ? No result? Incorrect result?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: nothing works mean... web element not found

Answer (score 1):

To be able to get text WebElement should be visible, that's why wait for visibility of all elements. Code examples to get all `a` elements (`total` is be a `list` of WebElements):

```
total = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul[uib-pagination] li a')))

# or

total = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.pagination-page a')))
```

To get text from `total`:

```
# texts of all links in total
total_texts = [element.text from element in total]
print(total_texts)

# text of the first one
first_page_number = total[0].text

# text of the last one
last_page_number = total[-1].text
```

Comment: OP is asking how to get "1"... half of your answer is ways to locate the element using "1". Also, `total` is a collection and you don't show how to get the text from that collection.